# Swift iOS UI Advice

Tags: swift, swift2

[image]

I am looking for some general advice and maybe some example code of what I am trying to accomplish if anyone knows of any for an iOS swift project. I would like to either:

A) Make the background, of the blue view, gray and only show a certain percent of the blue area.

OR

B) Overlay the gray area on top of the blue view and just keep making gray area bigger.

What I am trying to do is simulate battery power and show a battery.

I've considered using a progress bar and doing option A, but the blue area is NOT a solid color. Its actually an image. I've tried using an image for the progress bar, but the image needs to keep its dimensions. (Ex: If progress shows 20% it needs to show only 20% of the image or "blue area", but if you use an image as the progress bar it just shrinks the image and still shows 100% of it instead of just the 20% I need to show).

Comment: That's exactly what a progress bar is used to accomplish. If you've used 20% of the battery, set the progress bar to 80% done. If the battery drops by another 10%, reduce the progress bar by 10% to 70%. Doing this with a separate image is a useless waste of memory and resources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems like a better fit for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily write a custom self-drawing UIView that will behave in exactly the way you describe. In other words, you tell your UIView a percentage, and it redraws itself with the blue on the left and the gray on the right. You can even draw the darker gray stroke outline shown in your drawings. All easily accomplished in code.

Answer (score 2):

I like being able to lay things out visually and take advantage of autolayout.  Here's how I would do this (in a nib/storyboard):

1. Place a UIView on your canvas and give it the gray background.  Give it whatever autolayout constraints are appropriate for you.
2. Place a UIView inside the one from #1 and give it the blue background.  Anchor it's left, top, and bottom to the gray parent view and give it whatever width (doesn't matter).
3. Add an outlet to that width constraint you made in #2.
4. Now all you have to do is modify the "constant" property of that width constraint to give you the desired "progress".  So if your gray view is 100 wide and you want to present "20%" progress, then just do "yourWidthConstraint.constant = 20".